# Speech to Text Include speech engine in apk

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I need a speech to text facility in my app for Really non-Geeks. Is there a way to include the speech engine at compile time for all sorts of tablets?

Comment: Look here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html

Answer (score 3):

You could include your own engine, like the CMU Sphinx Engine. This has also the advantage of working without a data connection.

See this [post](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/) on how to install it on Android - however you have to change the Android.mk : Reverse the order of `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` so the line looks like this:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := pocketsphinx sphinxlm sphinxfeat sphinxfe sphinxutil
```

Otherwise the NDK will fail to build the package.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 (three!) such `Android.mk` files in the build tree:

1. CMUSphinx\AndroidPocketSphinx-master\bin\classes\Android.mk
2. CMUSphinx\AndroidPocketSphinx-master\jni\Android.mk
3. CMUSphinx\pocketsphinx-0.8\swig\Android.mk

The first 2 files (#1 & #2) already come in the order specified by @Force:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := pocketsphinx sphinxlm sphinxfeat sphinxfe sphinxutil
```

The 3rd one has a different order:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := sphinxutil sphinxfe sphinxfeat sphinxlm pocketsphinx
```

This **works out of the box!** That is, no need to change anything.

This refers to the package downloaded in April 2013, so perhaps an older download did require the aforementioned change.