# Android: Speech to Text and Speech Recognition Offline

Tags: android, voice-recognition, speech-to-text, offlineapps

I am stuck in one of my offline Android Application, where in I need Offline Speech Recognition and Speech to Text API.

Kindly share your views and input if anyone has worked on Offline Speech to Text and Speech Recognition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speech to Text Include speech engine in apk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644650/speech-to-text-include-speech-engine-in-apk)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839663/using-android-jellybeans-stand-alone-speech-recognizer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could include your own engine, like the CMU Sphinx Engine. This has also the advantage of working without a data connection.

See this [post](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/) on how to install it on Android - however you have to change the Android.mk : Reverse the order of `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` so the line looks like this:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := pocketsphinx sphinxlm sphinxfeat sphinxfe sphinxutil
```

Otherwise the NDK will fail to build the package.

Comment: The accuracy level of CMU Sphinx is very low... i have tried that.... but it was unable to recognize the speech...

Comment: well, don't expect to have good results with the included 3MB pronounciation file. on the CMU site are files more than 100MB big and they work pretty good (on a desktop, a mobile phone cannot handle them yet).
However CMU Sphinx is great for commands; you can create a language model with a few commands and the recognition rate is at about 99 per cent

Comment: The post on pocketsphinx installation is a bit outdated, the recent pocketsphinx howto is here: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid